# learning to use map and lambda in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

### The purpose of this script is to learn how to use `lambda` functions in conjunction with `map`.

I tried to insert a string to all columns of an sqlite table and no error is shown yet the values didn't change.

```py
class DB(SomeDbBase):

    def get_columns(self):
        res = self.get_cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM EVENTS")
        names = list(map(lambda x: x[0], res.description))
        return names`


    def update_to_last(self,column:str,data:str):
        c = self.get_cursor()
        print(column,data)
        c.execute(
                 f"UPDATE EVENTS SET 
                 '{column}'='{data}' WHERE ID ='(SELECT last_insert_rowid())'")
        self.conn.commit()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        d=DB()
        columns=d.get_columns()

        # this pile of map and lambda's ment to first get all of the columns names
        # then add to every string a pair of some fictionary "data" to a list
        # then the list is sent to update
        map(
           lambda x:d.update_to_last(x[0],x[1]),
           (list(map(lambda column:[column,"data"],columns)))
           )
```

Comment: **don't use `map` for side effects**.  That is confusing and unidiomatic. Just use a regular for-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` does not create a list of results. It produces items on demand as you iterate over the `map` instance. You aren't iterating over the `map` instance, so `update_to_last` never gets called on anything.

Don't use `map` for side effects. Use a regular `for` loop.

```
# No need to turn the map instance into a list first; you
# can iterate over the map directly.
for x in map(lambda column: [column, "data"], columns):
    d.update_to_last(x[0], x[1])
```

Of course, since `"data"` is the fixed value of `x[1]`, you really don't need `map` at all.

```
for column in columns;
    d.update_to_last(column, "data")
```

---

On the other hand, if `d.update_to_last` produced an interesting return value that you wanted to store in a list, you might do somethign like

```
from itertools import repeat
x = list(map(d.list_to_update, columns, repeat("data")))
```

although a list comprehension like

```
x = [d.list_to_update(c, "data") for c in columns]
```

would be preferable.

Comment: thanks, learnt a lot, but theoretically if i cast map to list it forces the map to yield until iteration exception is reached, am i right? if so then it would call d.update_to_last(column, "data") for all the  iterations?

Comment: Yes, `list` just does all the iteration at once in order to build a list. The point of using something like `map` is if you don't need all the items in memory at once, but instead just need the first one, which you can then discard before getting the second one, etc. You'll use a constant amount of memory rather than a linear amount.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this? (change the column name `id` accordingly)

`c.execute(f"UPDATE EVENTS SET '{column}'='{data}' WHERE id = (SELECT last_insert_rowid())")`

Comment: The opp wanted to learn map and lambda, how your answer helps with that?

Comment: Well, I think the issue is in the SQL statement instead of map and lambda